# How to connect metabase to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, driver, business-intelligence, metabase

I have the following snowflake url that I use to login to the snowsight UI: zgb07638.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com

I want my metabase to connect to snowflake BD,I have entered the above account name, But unfortunately I am getting an error as mentioned:
`JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Certificate for <zgb07638.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com.snowflakecomputing.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.prod3.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com, *.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com, *.global.snowflakecomputing.com, *.snowflakecomputing.com, *.prod3.us-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com].`

error screenshot:
[image]
Below is the screenshot of the metabase Snowflake connection page
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[image]

entered account name: zgb07638.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com

Answer (score 1):

The document says that you need to enter your Account ID with the region that your Snowflake cluster is running on:

zgb07638.us-east-1.aws

Please check the link: https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/databases/connections/snowflake

You shouldn't enter the full name.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem... the solution is to remove ".snowflakecomputing.com" from Account name.

Your account name should be stated as follows:

Account name: zgb07638.us-east-1

Comment: I suggest you don't share sensitive details like account name on the post.